# doCallRealMethod not working on void return type method

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to call a real method whose return type is void . I have tried both @mock and @spy both on my bean but it is still not going into actual class.

```
@Autowired private HelperV2 authValidationHelper;

@Override
public void postProcess(Event event) {
List<Error> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
  authValidationHelper.validateOrderTotalAmount(event, errorList);
  handleError(event, errorList);
}
}
```

Test case

```
@Spy private HelperV2 authValidationHelper;

@Test
public void test_postProcess()  {
BaseOrderEvent event =
    ParserUtil.getObjectFromFile(
        "events/createPaymentRequestWithShoppingCardOnly2.json", Event.class);
Mockito.doCallRealMethod()
    .when(authValidationHelper)
    .validateOrderTotalAmount(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
createOrderEventProcessor.postProcess(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a bean in spring context, you need a `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean`